# Activity refreshes upon notification click

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I have a mobile app which consumes a News API. I have created notifications which upon click open the app and find news in a particular category. When clicked the app opens with the proper news, however after half a second the news are swapped with others as if the API is called again which it isn't. Any idea why this behavior could be happening ?

Comment: how have you implemented the notification?

Comment: With the help of an AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver.